# T-SQL to determine lowest bit value in a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table that has an `int primary key`, a `varchar` and a `bit` value.  Please keep in mind that I'm not actually using anything like this but it illustrates what I'm trying to do in a `SELECT` statement.

Faux Table:

```
CREATE TABLE HorribleSample(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    IsTrue BIT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_HorribleSample PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Id ASC)
)
```

Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO HorribleSample VALUES('HELLO', 0)
INSERT INTO HorribleSample VALUES('WORLD', 1)
INSERT INTO HorribleSample VALUES('HELLO', 1)
INSERT INTO HorribleSample VALUES('WORLD', 1)
```

What I'm trying to do is select the lowest bit value from the result set.  I thought I could do:

```
SELECT MIN(IsTrue)
FROM HorribleSample
WHERE Code = 'HELLO'
```

But I get an error stating that I can't use `MIN` on a `bit` field.

When the code is `HELLO`, I would expect `0`, but when it's `WORLD` I would expect `1`.  How can I accomplish this?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM HorribleSample 
WHERE Code = 'HELLO' 
 ORDER BY IsTrue
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the bit into int

```
CAST(IsTrue as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(IsTrue AS INT))
FROM HorribleSample
WHERE Code = 'HELLO'
```

Good luck!